# Google cloud natural language API with SlackBot

Tags: node.js, api, google-cloud-platform

I try to follow this tutorial :

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/language/slackbot

The bot is running fine but it doesn't generate any thumbs up or down like it must do. It seems that it doesn't have access to Natural Language API. How can I debug it or be sure that it can access the API ?

Answer (score 0):

The range of the sentiment score returned by the API has changed since that example was written. The sample will be updated shortly to fix that.  In the meantime, try editing `demo_bot.js` to change the `SENTIMENT_THRESHOLD` to something around .3, e.g.
`const SENTIMENT_THRESHOLD = .3;`